# What is the best way to save list to a file and load id on pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to save and load list like this so I can load in other place

```
Index(['province_BANTEN', 'province_DKI JAKARTA', 'province_JAWA BARAT',
       ...
       'lending_count_l3', 'lending_cumcount_l2', 'lending_cumcount_l3'],
      dtype='object', length=341)
```

I try to save to csv `df.to_csv("model_column.csv")`, but `AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'to_csv'`

Is there any better Idea to save that

Comment: That is not a list. That is an `pandas.Index` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe construct a new dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=df)
df.to_csv("model_column.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pickle` module to save your dataframe such as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

# save dataframe as pickle
with open('model_columns.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(df, f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

# load dataframe as pickle
with open('model_columns.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    new_df = pickle.load(f)
```

`pickle` can convert a Python(eg. dataframe) object structure to a stream of bytes and store it.